# Joomla application interaction with mobile application

Tags: php, database, web-services, joomla

I am currently working on a project involving a Joomla application and a Mobile application. I so far have created both applications and now I want to link the Mobile application to the same database as is used within the joomla application.

I have done some research and it seems that to directly connect to the database is not the best option due to security reasons etc... The use of a web service is recommended.

My understanding of this is this is say for example I have a "player" table in my database which consists of players to output these players via the joomla application in an XML or JSON format which can then be accessed by the mobile application and parsed.

I am curious as to how to go about creating this webservice within the joomla application/framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of talk in the Joomla world about integrating this into the core in some way. There is even a web services working group, so this is going to be getting easier in the future.

In terms of something to work with, the best code that I have seen is still very sparse, but it could be a good start: https://github.com/techjoomla/Joomla-REST-API. This is by Tech Joomla. I haven't actually played with this code, but it looks to be implementing a REST api, which is probably what you want.

For more code, you may want to get in touch with the working group and see if they have beta code that you could help test and improve for your situation. http://docs.joomla.org/Web_Services_Working_Group

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also found http://docs.joomla.org/Xml-rpc_changes_in_Joomla!_1.6 which has helped me out